# $ad + cb = ac + bd$ s.t. $a < b$ and $c < d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, real-numbers

Is it possible to find numbers $a, b, c, d > 0$ such $a < b$ and $c < d$ and

$$
ad + cb = ac + bd
$$
?

**Attempt based on comment:**

Assume it is true, then
$$
ad + cb - ac - bd = a(d-c) + b(c-d) = 0
$$
Next,
$$
a(d-c) = b(d-c).
$$
Next, since $d\neq c$, we have
$$
a=b,
$$
which contradicts to the original assumption $a < b$.

Comment: Hint: factorize $ab+cd-ac-bd$, and find out if it is possible for this expression to be zero.

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake in the original question. I changed. But the hint is very useful

Comment: $ad+cb=ac+bd \implies a(d-c) = b(d-c) \implies a=b$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ad + cb = ac + bd$ is equivalent to $(a-b)(d-c) = 0$.  So we can have $c=d$ which contradicts the assumption $c<d$, or $a=b$ which contradicts the assumption $a<b$.

Hence, it is **not** possible to find numbers $a, b, c, d > 0$ such $a < b$ and $c < d$ and
$
ad + cb = ac + bd
$.